# Extending Custom Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using

```
Backbone.View.extend
```

I have created a Backbone View called **MyView**. In my view I've created a bunch of custom functions. The problem I'm having is that I need to create a new Backbone view that **extends MyView**.

I don't want to create a new View and duplicate code... I just want to utilize inheritance to extend functionality... Problem is that I don't know the way to do it exactly, and I also don't know how to call the **super** functions in Backbone.

*Edit - Thanks for the answers by some below, but still not quite sure how to call parent's method. For example:

```
// in subView
{
initialize: function(){
// would like to do something like super.initialize()
 // here i would then declare variables exclusive to subview
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
 var NewView = MyView.extend({
     //Usual config goes on in here, and it will have inherited functions
     //And default properties from MyView
 });
```

Or, if you are looking to call the super class then there is an implementation of it here:
http://forrst.com/posts/Backbone_js_super_function-4co

Comment: I see, but how would I call the parent's method?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following you... say the MyView had the method doSomething(), then when you create NewView by extending MyView, you should be able to call NewView.doSomething();

Comment: I have not. but that looks sweet. can you update your answer and include that link (just for anyone else who's looking for how to do it).

Comment: Btw, that link is for Backbone.Model, replacing Backbone.Model with Backbone.View seems to work

Comment: Links are dead. Can pepz stop linking to the ever pawned, forrst.com.

Answer (score 7):

```
var SubView = MainView.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newView = MyView.extend()
```

Comment: perfect, but how would i call the parent methods/functions inside an override function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how useful this is, but if you enter compile this coffeescript:

```
class BaseView extends Backbone.View

class MyView extends Baseview
```

It generates this:

```
(function() {
  var BaseView, MyView,
    __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor; child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

  BaseView = (function(_super) {

    __extends(BaseView, _super);

    function BaseView() {
      BaseView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return BaseView;

  })(Backbone.View);

  MyView = (function(_super) {

    __extends(MyView, _super);

    function MyView() {
      MyView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return MyView;

  })(Baseview);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: God that makes my eyes bleed

Comment: @tkone Sure, but look at the coffeescript :)

Comment: thats to what I was referring! :)